# Issue with leet code problem 3 Longest substring

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Essentially we are asked to find, given a string, the longest substring with no repeating characters, below I am using the sliding window approach.

Examples:

```cpp
Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
```

```cpp
Input: s = "bbbbb"
Output: 1
Explanation: The answer is "b", with the length of 1.
```

```cpp
Input: s = "pwwkew"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "wke", with the length of 3.
Notice that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.
```

My attempt:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(std::string s){
        
        int count{0};
        std::map<char,int> char_map;
        std::vector<char> char_vec;
        auto left{char_vec.begin()};
        auto right{char_vec.begin()};
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char_vec.push_back(s[i]);
            if(char_map.find(s[i]) != char_map.end()){
                char_map[s[i]]++;                    
            }
            else{
                char_map.insert(std::pair<char,int>{s[i],1});   
                
            }
            while(++right != char_vec.end() && char_map[*(right)] > 1){
                char_map[*(left++)]--;            
            }
            count = (count < std::distance(left,right)) ? std::distance(left,right) : count;   
        }
        return count;                
    }
};
```

However, there is an issue in the while loop near the end of the code block that is causing
[compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brrL0.png) and am very confused about how to solve it.

Comment: That's not a compiler error. The error happens when you run your program, so it's a runtime error.

Comment: I recommend you create a proper [mre] that you can build and run locally on your own system. If you get any errors, you get the full context of any possible problem, not a possible abbreviated variant that those sites might present. Also you can use a debugger to catch crashes and other problems, and step through your code line by line to find other problems.

Comment: *and am very confused about how to solve it.* -- You use a debugger, just as any other programmer who writes a program that has issues with their program does.  Those websites such as leetcode do not emphasize debugging, and this is obvious by the number of leetcode questions that show up here with no debugging effort.

Answer (score 2):

So your code is suffering from *iterator invalidation*. Here you have a vector

```
std::vector<char> char_vec;
```

and here you create two iterators to that vector

```
auto left{char_vec.begin()};
auto right{char_vec.begin()};
```

and then here you add an item to that vector

```
char_vec.push_back(s[i]);
```

When you add an item to a vector you may *invalidate* any iterators to that vector, and any use of such iterators causes your program to have *undefined behaviour*.

Instead of using iterators you could try using *offsets* (i.e. integer variables which you use to index the vector). These have the advantage that they are not invalidated as the vector grows.

For more information on iterator invalidation see the table on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Different containers have different behaviour wrt iterator invalidation.

Comment: Iterators could still be used. Just declare them on the string and do the work using just the string and map. There is literally no reason for the vector to exist.

Comment: ahh tytyty so much makes sense